# How to view ENS name from transaction?

Tags: addresses, ens, auctions

[This is ethereum address.](https://etherscan.io/address/0x00bda1105ce38848b890c138d3d23a0435790a39)
On which there are a bunch of registered [ENS](https://ens.domains/) names

How can we view the actual ENS names which were registered/won in auctions from this address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this site [enslisting](https://enslisting.com/manage/home) . Search for one of you names, and it will show all the names owned by that address.

you have 13233 ENS domains

[image]